# Vue JS - button disabled before all validation errors are met

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, button, vuejs2

I have a button that is meant to be disabled before all validation requirements are met. However the button is disabled only when I click it the first time and allow the validation errors to show up. I would like my button to be disabled from the beginning until all inputs are entered accordingly. Can someone assist with this, please?

Form component

```
<template>
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(sendFormData)" novalidate>
      <slot name="form-content"/>
      <slot name="button-submit" :is-invalid="isInvalid"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

inputs component (only showing the button section for this part):

```
<template #button-submit="{isInvalid}">
   <button :disabled="isInvalid && !selectedTown"
      :class="{'button-main-disabled': isInvalid && !selectedTown}"
      type="submit"
      class="button-main button-add">
      School toevoegen
   </button>
</template>
```

Comment: Use isInvalid as a computed each time the data changes the isInvalid property will be updated

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `isInvalid` is a data property, initialize it to `true`, and only change it to `false` when you confirm the inputs are valid (in `handleSubmit()`):

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isInvalid: true 
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleSubmit() {
      // validate data...

      this.isInvalid = false /* data is valid */
    }
  }
}
```

Also, your `disabled` binding looks incorrect. It disables the button when the form specifies an invalid state *AND* when no town is selected, but I think you meant to use an *OR* condition (assuming that a town selection is required).

```js
:disabled="isInvalid && !selectedTown" ❌
                     ^^

:disabled="isInvalid || !selectedTown" ✅
```